# Search Date on channel field of type date

Tags: channel-entries

I have a form which will have a date range split into day month year as 3 individual HTML select options for FROM and TO -

From: SELECT option day, month year

To: SELECT option day, month, year

I need to search on a channel field of type date (Currently stored as a UNIX time stamp)

What would be the best solution to get the entire range to search and how best to convert the date supplied?

I am not seeing the default search functionality will help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two search addons that may help:

[**Low Search**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-search)

> Limiting entries by a given range, based on channel fields;

---

**[Super Search](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/super-search)**

> Anything you might want to search for... keywords, channels, categories, statuses, authors, custom fields, **date ranges**, custom field numeric ranges, etc, can be loaded into a single URI segment with the Super Search syntax.

Comment: Great! If my answer helped, select it as Correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left.